# how to put opencart 3.0 customer name on header?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

Can Any one help me how to display customer name in header after 
customer's login

I also try some code but dosen't work 
in `controller>common>header.php`

```
$data['customer_firstname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();
$data['customer_lastname'] = $this->customer->getLastName();
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: How to close drop-down automatic in opencart

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit these files:

**Controller** `catalog/controller/common/header.php`

**Find**: `return $this->load->view('common/header', $data);`

**Add before it:**

```
if($this->customer->isLogged()){
    $data['text_customer_name'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_customer_name'), $this->customer->getFirstName(), $this->customer->getLastName());
} else {
    $data['text_customer_name'] = $this->language->get('text_account');
}
```

**Language** `catalog/language/*/common/header.php`

**Add:** `$_['text_customer_name'] = 'Hi %s %s';`

**View** `catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.twig`

**Find**: `{{ text_account }}`

**Replace with**: `{{ text_customer_name }}`

Comment: It's working for me. Did you clear your caches? ocmod, vqmod and twig caches?

Comment: yes sir its shows me something like . $Data['Customer_firstname'] = $This->Customer->GetFirstName(); $Data['Customer_lastname'] = $This->Customer->GetLastName();

Comment: How to remove this error  $Data['Customer_firstname'] = $This->Customer->GetFirstName(); $Data['Customer_lastname'] = $This->Customer->GetLastName(); showing in front end side above my account

Comment: You're welcome. glad your problem solved. if my answer helped you, you can upvote or accept it.

Comment: Can You Help me how to close drop-down automatic once we move cursor its close drop down actully i want to close drop-down of my-account .  @DigitCart

Comment: You must ask you question as a new topic.